# Standalone App crashes after some time

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have developed a standalone application using Java7 and Spring. When I deploy the application on CloudFoundry everything works fine at the beginning. When I run `mvn cf:apps` I see all apps have the status `STARTED`. However after some hours it seems the app crashes, its status is still `STARTED` but when I try to retrieve the logs I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.0.0.M4:logs (default-cli) on project [....]: An exception was caught while executing Mojo. 500 Internal Server Error -> [Help 1]
```

When I redeploy the application, it works again, but only for some time. I also noticed the following phenomen, when I check the deployed apps with the VMC tool instead of Maven, then the standalone apps do not show as running, but instead their status is `0%`:

```
name             status    usage      runtime   url                                          
standaloneapp1   0%        2 x 512M   java7     standaloneapp1.cloudfoundry.com
standaloneapp2   0%        1 x 512M   java7     standaloneapp2.cloudfoundry.com                   
webapp           running   1 x 512M   java7     webapp.cloudfoundry.com
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is it normal that the VMC tools shows standalone apps status as `0%`?
2. How can I get more information about my applications, to find out what goes wrong?

P.S: My standalone apps seem to require quite a lot of RAM, when I ran the standalone apps with 128MB or 256MB then I always got out of memory errors. When I run the apps locally they do not need that much ram, both apps only have a small main method and some beans for RabbitMQ and MongoDB. I'm not sure if this problem is related though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more information about your apps, use the "vmc logs " command.

However, Cloud Foundry v1 is going away after Jun 30th so you may want to consider migrating your apps to v2 running at run.pivotal.io (new docs at docs.cloudfoundry.com).

Comment: As I wrote in my question, the VMC tool crashes with internal error 500 when i run `vmc logs <app name>`, so I am not able to retrieve the logs.

Comment: doh, apologies I had missed the fact that you had already tried vmc logs! Can you try deploying to run.pivotal.io using the new cf tool?

Comment: Unfortunately I was using the free account for v1 and I do not have a paid account. So I cannot try that. I guess since v1 is going away this next week it doesn't really matter. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: you can still try the service for free (which I hope you will do) and also get support at support.cloudfoundry.com. Thanks.